# Can't Access Objects Stored In Real Time Database

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!)
    { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            self.warningLabel.isHidden = false;
            self.passwordTextField.text = "";
        } else {
            guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {
                print("no uid");
                return
            }

            //PROBLEM AREA
            let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)/profile")

            databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                print("profile: \(snapshot)")

                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    let array:NSArray = snapshot.children.allObjects as NSArray

                    for obj in array {
                        let snapshot:DataSnapshot = obj as! DataSnapshot
                        if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                        {
                            if let name = childSnapshot["name"] as? String {
                                print(name)
                            } else {
                                print("no name retrieved");
                            }
                            if let profileImageURL = childSnapshot["profileImageURL"] as? String {
                                print(profileImageURL)
                            } else {
                                print("no profile image retrieved");
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }


            print("Log in succesful")
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "welcomeSeg", sender: self)
        }
    }

}
```

I find the documentation (or maybe my searching skills) to be sort of lacking. My profile snapshot just shows up as empty although I'm certain there is data there.

My database layout is as follows:

[image: database layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're observing a single user's profile. That means that your snapshot contains the properties of that single user, and you don't need to loop over its children as you do right now.

So something like this:

```
let databaseRef = Database.database().reference().child("users/\(uid)/profile")

databaseRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if(snapshot.exists()) {
        if let childSnapshot = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
          if let name = snapshot["name"] as? String {
            print(name)
          } else {
            print("no name retrieved");
          }
          if let profileImageURL = snapshot["profileImageURL"] as? String {
            print(profileImageURL)
          } else {
            print("no profile image retrieved");
          }
        }
    }
}
```